# How to make NIntegrate automatically resort to arbitrary precision if machine precision fails?

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy, message-coding

Sometimes `NIntegrate` gives me messages like `NIntegrate::slwcon` or `NIntegrate::ncvb` when I use the default `WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision`. I'd like to still use `MachinePrecision` by default, since for most entries in my table it works normally, but when an integration emits a warning to automatically switch to arbitrary precision with e.g. `WorkingPrecision->16`.

My current approach is like this:

```
Check[#[MachinePrecision], #[16]]&[NIntegrate[func[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision->#]&]
```

but it emits the message when first argument of `Check` does. I can't use `Quiet` on the whole expression, since it'll suppress the messages from the fallback with 16-digit arbitrary precision arithmetic, which is undesired.

Is there a better way? Maybe there's an option for `NIntegrate` to do just this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Catch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch.html)/[`Throw`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Throw.html) or [`CheckAbort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CheckAbort.html)/[`Abort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abort.html) could be used.  `Catch` seems the better alternative, since an `Abort` could conceivably arise internally or from user action.

Example, which fails to converge at `MachinePrecision` but converges at a precision of `16`:

```
NIntegrate[D[Sinc[1.*^-9 + x^3], x] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.00778142}. NIntegrate obtained -6.02337*10^-10 and 6.303937076607007`*^-16 for the integral and error estimates.
>
> ```
> (*  -6.02337*10^-10  *)
> ```

```
Catch[
   Quiet@Check[#[MachinePrecision],
     Throw[Hold[#[16]], "HighPrecision"]],
   "HighPrecision",
   ReleaseHold[#] &] &[
 NIntegrate[D[Sinc[0.000000001 + x^3], x] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> #] &]
```

> ```
> (*  -6.023378398711190*10^-10  *)
> ```

Example, which gives messages in both cases:

```
Catch[
    Quiet@Check[
      #[MachinePrecision],
      Throw[Hold[#[16]], "HighPrecision"]],
    "HighPrecision",
    ReleaseHold[#] &] &[
 NIntegrate[Sin[x^3 + Exp[x]], {x, -10, 10}, 
   Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", WorkingPrecision -> #] &]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly....
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy....
>
> ```
> (* 1.034822168789827  *)
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid suppressing messages from `#[16]`? Or does it actually not suppress them (is it evaluated in `Catch` instead of `Check`?)? BTW, which version of Mathematica did you use to test this? I don't get any messages whatsoever with your _Example_ in Mathematica 11.

Comment: @Ruslan Oops, I got careless going back and forth between `CheckAbort` and `Catch`. Should work now. -- I'm using V11 (Mac OS 10.11.6), and the first example gives an error as shown for me. If you have an example that would better illustrate your issue, perhaps you could post it. I had to randomly make the integrand pathological to find one I thought illustrated the problem.

Comment: Strange, your first example doesn't give me any messages on Kubuntu 14.04. Anyway, I get the idea with the `Hold` inside `Quiet` and `ReleaseHold` in `Catch` action, it does work. Thanks.